# Used MacPorts to install WordPress. Where is it now?

Tags: bash, wordpress, shell, terminal, macports

I used MacPorts shell to download and install WordPress:

```
port install wordpress
```

It went just fine:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for libxml2
--->  Fetching libxml2
--->  Attempting to fetch libxml2-2.7.5.tar.gz from http://arn.se.distfiles.macports.org/libxml2
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for libxml2
--->  Extracting libxml2
--->  Configuring libxml2
--->  Building libxml2
--->  Staging libxml2 into destroot
--->  Deactivating libxml2 @2.7.4_0
--->  Computing dependencies for libxml2
--->  Installing libxml2 @2.7.5_0
--->  Activating libxml2 @2.7.5_0
--->  Cleaning libxml2
--->  Computing dependencies for wordpress
--->  Fetching php5-web
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for php5-web
--->  Extracting php5-web
--->  Configuring php5-web
--->  Building php5-web
--->  Staging php5-web into destroot
--->  Installing php5-web @5.3.0_0
--->  Activating php5-web @5.3.0_0
--->  Cleaning php5-web
--->  Fetching wordpress
--->  Attempting to fetch wordpress-2.8.4.tar.gz from http://arn.se.distfiles.macports.org/wordpress
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for wordpress
--->  Extracting wordpress
--->  Configuring wordpress
--->  Building wordpress
--->  Staging wordpress into destroot
--->  Installing wordpress @2.8.4_0
--->  Activating wordpress @2.8.4_0
--->  Cleaning wordpress
```

But where did the files actually **go**? How can I trace that path? Having tons of WP stuff on my drive doesn't make it any easier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This lists all installed files:

```
port contents wordpress | more
```

Answer (score 1):

First you may have a look at this page: http://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#defaultprefix

And secondly I have to ask why do you want to install WP through port anyway? If you're not running a Server that needs to have a WP installation somewhere it's better to download the zip from the web site and use something like XAMPP, MAMP or the built-in Apache Server to work on the WP files.

Answer (score 0):

Just download Wordpress manually and unzip and install in a directory under `HD/Users/username/Sites/public_html/`

Use PhpMyAdmin to set up your database, and then view the site under `http://localhost/~username/public_html/`

Answer (score 0):

You might also think about pulling WordPress manually through SVN. You'll have much tighter control over what you get.

http://wordpress.org/download/svn/

Another thing that I don't like about pulling WordPress through MacPorts is that with its dependencies an upgrade of WordPress could trigger an upgrade of PHP, Apache, or MySQL, or all 3 at once... I'd much prefer to NOT have blog software dictate the upgrade of my server software, even if it is for local development.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
find / -name "wp-config*.php" -print
```